# How to do continuum approximation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, solid-state-physics, continuum-mechanics

Assume you have $N$ matrix fields $T_{j}$ on a 1d lattice with lattice constant unity. Now consider a sum like the following (you can think of the traces as supertraces), and subject it to a continuum approximation and keep only the integral term you get

$\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\mathrm{Tr}\left(T_{j}^{-1}T_{j+1}\right)\simeq\int ds\mathrm{Tr}\left(T^{-1}(s)\partial_{s}T(s)\right)$.

My question is now how to obtain an continuus integral expression if one considers the following sum ($a\neq1$):

$\mathrm{Tr}\left(T_{1}^{-1}T_{2}\right)+a\mathrm{Tr}\left(T_{2}^{-1}T_{3}\right)+\mathrm{Tr}\left(T_{3}^{-1}T_{4}\right)+a\mathrm{Tr}\left(T_{4}^{-1}T_{5}\right)+\ldots$

Maybe one way is to set $T_{j}=\exp(W_{j})T_{0}\exp(-W_{j})$? I am happy to see different approaches or references to related examples in the literature. I would expect the relevant integral term to be of the form $c(a)\int ds\mathrm{Tr}\left(\widetilde{T}^{-1}(s)\partial_{s}\widetilde{T}(s)\right)$ with some function $c(a)$ and somehow redefined fields.